# Getting a Javascript error in IE7 but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

Okay, so I'm writing some Javascript for a simple effect: when a drop down gets selected, a series of options will appear, depending on which one is chosen. This works great in Firefox, but when I went to test it on Internet Explorere, things weren't so pretty. It failed with, what is oh so helpful, and unknown runtime error. So, here is the HTML (simplified) for the setup. Pretty simple stuff:

```
<form>
   <ul>
      <li>
         <label class="description" for="request_type">Type of request </label>
         <div>
            <select onchange="vrf.VRDescChange(this.value)" name="request_type"> 
               <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
               <option value="Business Trip">Business Trip</option>    
            </select>
         </div> 
      </li>
      <span id="otheroptions">
         <li>
            <input type="text" id="Name"></input>
         </li> 
      </span>
   </ul>
</form>
```

A note: "vrf" is properly instantiated. When the page loads, the "otheroptions" span is hidden, until something gets selected from the "request_type" drop down. So, here is the code for the Javascript (again, simplified):

```
VRFunctions.prototype.VRDescChange = function(value) {    
   if (value === "Business Trip") {
      document.getElementById("otheroptions").style.display = "block";
   }
}
```

As you can see, I'm using Prototypes for the Javascript. Could this have something to do with it? Any elightenment would be most helpful.

Comment: What message is provided about the error?

Comment: The message is "Unknown Runtime Error" with a code of 0.

Also, this in IE7.

Comment: As a side note, your LI elements should be in a list of some sort, OL or UL.

Comment: They are on the actual site...I just neglected to put it here. Oops!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Firebug Lite to debug it in IE?  (http://getfirebug.com/lite.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
vrf.VRDescChange(this.form)
```

I think above line is behaving differently in Firefox and in IE.

Change your SELECT to

```
 <select onchange="vrf.VRDescChange(this)" name="request_type">
```

And use this JS:

```
VRFunctions.prototype.VRDescChange = function(el) {    
   if(el.options[el.selectedIndex].value === "Business Trip") {
      document.getElementById("otheroptions").style.display = "block";
   }
}
```

I would advice you to look up how you can attach your event handlers unobtrusively.

**EDIT:**

Fixed code.

**EDIT:**

What is the value of 'vrf' here?

Try this code: ([Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/onigu))

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Sandbox</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
body { background-color: #000; font: 16px Helvetica, Arial; color: #fff; }
#otheroptions { display: none; }
</style>

<script>
function handleChange(el)
{
   var value = el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;
   document.getElementById("otheroptions").style.display = value === '' ? 'none' : 'block';
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Hello from JS Bin</p>
  <p id="hello"></p>
<form>
   <ul>
      <li>
         <label class="description" for="request_type">Type of request </label>
         <div>
            <select onchange="handleChange(this)" name="request_type"> 
               <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
               <option value="Business Trip">Business Trip</option>    
            </select>
         </div> 
      </li>
      <span id="otheroptions">
         <li>
            <input type="text" id="Name"></input>
         </li> 
      </span>
   </ul>
</form>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If that is the case, then why does it work just peachily in Firefox? this.form is clearly returning something.

Comment: My raw DOM knowledge is getting rusty, 'this' does refer to the current element. I think 'this.form' behaves differently in IE and Firefox. In any case, instead of passing the form, you can pass the select object itself and check it's value.

Comment: Also, this did not fix the problem.

Comment: I just fixed the code to find the 'value' for the select element. 'SELECT' element doesn't have value property like 'input' element does.

Comment: With the new changes, it still doesn't solve the issue. However, this way does seem a lot cleaner (and less cumbersome) than passing in the whole form. Thank you.

Comment: It just doesn't work :-p I'm still getting the Javascript error in IE.

Comment: What is the vrf variable here?

Comment: I think you need to post the complete code. I have created a sample page which works and illustrates the technique. Check my original post.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `VRDescChange` in the select element's `onChange` handler, why are you passing `this.form` when you then go on to reference the `select` element in the function:

```
if(form.request_type.value === "Business Trip") {
```

Surely it would make more sense to pass `this` as the argument to `VRDescChange` instead of `this.form` in the `onChange` handler

Also, to get the selected value you want to use:

```
var rt; //Set this to reference the request_type select element
var selectedvalue = rt.options[rt.selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be related to setting a display style of "block" on a span element.  I seem to remember that IE gets very finicky about what styles get set on which elements.

Try changing the display style to "inline" and see if it still complains:

```
document.getElementById("otheroptions").style.display = "inline";
```

Comment: No luck there. I feel like the error is specifically with JavaScript, at least right now. The error is a javascript error, and as a result, IE refuses to run any of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your example works just fine in IE7. My guess is there is some other issue. I would look at your VRFunctions object.

```
<script>
   (function(){
      VRFunctions = function(){};
      VRFunctions.prototype.VRDescChange = function(value) {    
         if (value === "Business Trip") {
            document.getElementById("otheroptions").style.display = "block";
         }
      };
    vrf = new VRFunctions();

   }());
</script>

<form>
   <ul>
      <li>
         <label class="description" for="request_type">Type of request </label>
         <div>
            <select onchange="vrf.VRDescChange(this.value)" name="request_type"> 
               <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
               <option value="Business Trip">Business Trip</option>    
            </select>
         </div> 
      </li>
      <span id="otheroptions" style="display:none">
         <li>
            <input type="text" id="Name"></input>
         </li> 
      </span>
   </ul>
</form>
```